# Include member.php without using the whole URL

Tags: php

I have a folder called users. Users contains this:

```
*username*/index.php
member.php
```

`*username*` is the username of someone who has signed up. There are several `*username*` folders and they all contain index.php.

Since index.php in `*username*/` is past `member.php`, how do I include `member.php` in `index.php` without using the whole URL? I already tried `users/member.php` and `/users/member.php`, but it says the directory doesn't exist. I can't use the whole URL, because it messes up my PHP. How do I include `member.php` without using the whole URL?

Answer (score 3):

As long as username/index.php doesn't change the current working directory, you can simply use a relative path:

```
include '../members.php';
```

If it does change the cwd, just include the relative path from whatever the cwd is.  You can find out what the current working directory of a script is by:

```
echo getcwd();
```

Answer (score 0):

In filesystems, the string `../` represents going up one directory.

```
include("../members.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

That structure sounds weird. Anyway, you can use

```
include __DIR__.'/../member.php'
```

You can also use simple

```
include '../member.php'
```

but only if index.php is you starting script (i.e. what you type in browser to start application)